# C++ How do I Expand/Factorise equation (without solving it)

Tags: c++, math, equation

I'm a beginner in C++ and am trying to find if there is a function that allows to "scan" an input in order to detect the type of equation entered.

Basically, what I'm trying to do is enter something like `(a-b)^2` and the program would expand it to `a^2-2*a*b+b^2` or enter `ax^2+by+c` and the program would give me `a(x-α)+β`.

What I have previously done is simply ask for what type of equation is going to be entered and then ask specifically what is each factor (like this) :

```
int a, a2;
int b, b2;
int inbetween;
cout << "Equation of type (ax+by)^2.\nPlease enter the factor of X : ";
cin >> a;
cout << "Please enter the factor of Y : ";
cin >> b;
a2 = a*a; //pow(a,2)
b2 = b*b; //pow(b,2)
inbetween = 2*a*b;
cout << "(" << a << "x + " << b << "y" << ")^2 = " << a2 << "x + " << inbetween << "xy + " << b2 << "y\n";
// (ax + by)^2 = a^2x + 2*a*b*xy + b^2y
```

But this is exactly what I do not want to do.

I'd like to know if there is a way to expand the input for any type of equation that the coded program supports.

I hope I am being clear enough, english isn't my main language I see that what I'm trying to communicate isn't really clear.

Comment: Search [softwarerecs.se].  Software recommendations are off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I don't this Fast Banana is asking for what technology to use ; only for whether there is an easy way of solving this problem.

Comment: The most reliable way to implement a function which detects the inputted expression's mathematical order and other features is to write an expression parser using a common tool like boost's spirit. This however is not necessarily a task for a novice. But you have to learn somehow.

Comment: Yes I am indeed looking for an "expression parser" as @JimmyNJ said. I will now have a look into the subject, thanks a lot.

Comment: Maybe you can also query an existing webservice for that, maybe wolfram alpha or similar sites provide an api for that. An expression parser would take alot of hours I guess..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is clear enough (it's actually a very interesting question IMO).

Yes, this is possible, but as far as I know there is no easy way of doing this ; you would have to program this yourself. I think your program is fine the way it is.

There is a whole area of mathematics called *language theory* which studies the sort of problem you just asked. To give you an idea of the solution of this sort of problem, the best way of solving this is writing your own grammar. You would have to elaborate the grammar rules formally before writing the parser, and implement the rules using [regular expressions](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/) (then [you would have two problems](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/223634/what-is-meant-by-now-you-have-two-problems) ;D ).

From the looks of your problem, this would require so much programming that, say, 95% of your code would be to decide what sort of expression it is and extract the values, and the remaining 5% would be just to expand or factorize. An excessive effort for a simple program, if you ask me.

Comment: The two links you've provided are very interesting! I'm having a look at regular expressions, but then those are exactly and only what I need aren't they? From the brief look I had they correspond exactly to what i was asking, I'll have a deeper look into those and Boost's Spirit, thank you and @JimmyNJ

Comment: @FastBanana As I mentioned in my answer, I only explained this so you could understand how to solve this sort of problem. If you are a beginner at C++, I would encourage you to learn the basics *first* before digging into more advanced things like regular expressions. I would say, come back to regular expressions in a few months if you are still interested.

Answer (score 2):

I think Anthony D. has summed up the answer nicely, basically you're looking for a lexical analyzer and parser. If you are interested in learning more, it's worth directing you (and others that might find your question) towards the [Yacc documentation](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/yacc/index.html). Although much of the documentation is Yacc specific, it is well written and detailed enough that it will help you reason through the different challenges and complexities of this problem. Plus, there are plenty of Yacc calculator examples that you can use as a reference if you eventually want to build a calculator.

Comment: Excellent suggestion. Also, those who want to actually make basic languages (like calculators) should also look into Flex (the "**f**ast **lex**ical analyzer"), which is a related technology that easily recognizes patterns. Flex and Yacc are often used together, flex to recognize patterns, and Yacc to perform actions when patterns are found.